# Calculate a 30-day rolling hurst exponent

Tags: python-3.x

I have the hurst function:

```
def hurst(ts):
    """Returns the Hurst Exponent of the time series vector ts"""
    # Create the range of lag values
    lags = range(2, 100)

    # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
    tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]

    # Use a linear fit to estimate the Hurst Exponent
    poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)

    # Return the Hurst exponent from the polyfit output
    return poly[0]*2.0
```

I have a mean-reverting time series:

```
mr  = log(randn(100000)+1000)
```

The mean-reverting time series has a hurst exponent close to zero as it should:

```
print ("Hurst(MR) :", np.round(hurst(mr), 4))
```

I put the mean-reverting time series in a df:

```
meanreversion = {'Data': mr} 
meanreversion = pd.DataFrame(meanreversion)
```

I can calculate the hurst exponent for the first 30 days:

```
[(-i, hurst(ts = meanreversion['Data'][:-i])) for i in range( 1, 30 )]
```

I'm having trouble calculating a rolling hurst exponent. In the "Rolling Hurst" column, it should take the hurst exponent from the "Data" column for the previous 30 days, then move forward one row and calculate the hurst exponent for the previous 30 days, and so on. Here's what I tried:

```
meanreversion['Rolling Hurst'] = [(-i, hurst(ts = meanreversion['Data'][:-i])) for i in range( 1, 30 )]
```

I got this message: "Length of values does not match length of index"

I also tried:

```
meanreversion['Rolling Hurst'] = meanreversion['Data'].rolling(30).apply(hurst)
```

And got this message: "SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares"

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer with the below code, but I'd be excited to get anyone's thoughts.

```
pip install hurst

H, c, data = compute_Hc(meanreversion['Data'], kind='price', simplified=True)

roll_days   = 252 #choose whatever time period you want
roll_prices = meanreversion['Data'].rolling(roll_days)

roll_prices.apply(lambda x: hurst(x))

Rolling1 = roll_prices.apply(lambda x: hurst(x))
Rolling1 = pd.DataFrame(Rolling1)

RollingFinal = Rolling1.dropna()
RollingFinal = pd.DataFrame(RollingFinal)
RollingFinal.head(2)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot(RollingFinal, color='b', label='Rolling Hurst')
```

Comment: What does the function hurst in roll_prices.apply(lambda x: hurst(x)) refer to?